# Install multiple ios app simultaneously in a third party app

Tags: ios

I developed an app that can download and install the 3rd party apps that I managed one by one. I am wondering if there is way that I can have the "install all" button to download and install multiple apps simultaneously. I am currently implementing my code using this url "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=...".

Comment: feels like a cheating app. you will be rejected by apple.

Comment: This is being used internally and we never planed to release to app store.